# How to dynamically allocate 2D array and pass it into function

Tags: c++

```
void Insert(float** Array, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
            cin >> Array[i][j];
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    float** Array = new float*[n];
    Insert(Array,n);
    return 0;
}
```

Code above was my barebone attempt at passing and inserting values into dynamically allocated array, the code compiles and lets me input value **n** but inputing the very first number into the array results in this exception:

```
0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xCDCDCDCD.
```

I believe theres a problem with the way im inserting into the array but cant quite figure it out. Also Ive read about 0xCDCDCDCD and that im trying to write into non-existent memory or what not but cant figure it out, also the **j** value is supposed to be less than 6 for a reason.

Comment: Closed as a dupe of the canonical.  You forgot to loop through the `n` pointers you created and assign them a `new` address as well.

Comment: using a `std::vector<std::array<int,6>>` instead will save you from lots of pain

Comment: `0xCDCDCDCD` means uninitialized heap memory: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127386/in-visual-studio-c-what-are-the-memory-allocation-representations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127386/in-visual-studio-c-what-are-the-memory-allocation-representations)